# Authentication in Django Rest framework using django-auth-adfs

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, adfs

I am using the `django-auth-afs` python library to authenticate and protect my DRF API.  I have registered my app in Azure and have `client_id`, `client_secret` and `tenant_id`. Can someone help to tell me how to configure the django rest framework?

I have tried out the following documentation

https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest_framework.html
https://django-auth-adfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/azure_ad_config_guide.html#step-1-register-a-backend-application

My current configuration in `settings.py`

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAuthCodeBackend',
    'django_auth_adfs.backend.AdfsAccessTokenBackend',
)

AUTH_ADFS = {
    'AUDIENCE': client_id,
    'CLIENT_ID': client_id,
    'CLIENT_SECRET': client_secret,
    'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name',
                      'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn'},
    'GROUPS_CLAIM': 'roles',
    'MIRROR_GROUPS': True,
    'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'upn',
    'TENANT_ID': tenant_id,
    'RELYING_PARTY_ID': client_id,
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {  # type: ignore
    # disable this until Azure SSO integration done
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'django_auth_adfs.rest_framework.AdfsAccessTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
```

When to try to access my API I get response back but it should throw `Unauthorised` message and When I try to access the `/admin` page I get the following error

```
022-06-09 08:36:33,718 - INFO - django_auth_adfs - django_auth_adfs loaded settings from ADFS server.
2022-06-09 08:36:33,718 - INFO - django_auth_adfs - django_auth_adfs loaded settings from ADFS server.
2022-06-09 08:36:33,718 - INFO - django_auth_adfs - operating mode:         openid_connect
2022-06-09 08:36:33,718 - INFO - django_auth_adfs - operating mode:         openid_connect
......
2022-06-09 08:36:33,719 - DEBUG - django_auth_adfs - django_auth_adfs authentication backend was called but no authorization code was received
2022-06-09 08:36:33,719 - DEBUG - django_auth_adfs - django_auth_adfs authentication backend was called but no authorization code was received
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I might be late, but for future reference, the guide is incomplete. You have to go into the app in azure, and in the authentication section check "Access Tokens"

Comment: still not working. I have to change something else?